# Hibernate: saving one-2-one obligatory relationship

Tags: hibernate, persistence

I have two entities: **A** and **B**. **B** use the same PK as **A** entity. **A** and **B** linked with **one-2-one**, **optional** = false assosiation.

**What I do:**

```
//in session scope
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.setB(b);
b.setA(a);
session.save(a); 
session.flush(); //EXCEPTION!
```

**Exception:**

*org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:* ERROR: insert or update on table "B" violates foreign key constraint "fk_A_pk"
  Detail: Key (id)=(5600) is not present in table "A"

**What a problem:**

Due to **PS3** I can't save **A** with null **B**-property, because relationship is obligatory. But I can't 
save **A** with not-null property, because **A** haven't aID yet, and **B** can't imagine own id.

**Question:**

How could I save **A & B** entities?

**PS1**
B.PK is simultaneously a FK to A.PK field.

**PS2**
From the **generated sql**, I see that Hibernate try to proceed *'insert into B ...'* query, before it proceed *'insert into A'*.

**PS3**

*A class:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "a_sequence", sequenceName = "sq_a")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "a_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long aID;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private B b;
}
```

*B class:*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="b")
public class B {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="a"))
    private long aID;

    @JsonIgnore
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private A a;
}
```

**ADDITION (PostgreSQL DDL):**

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_file PRIMARY KEY (id )
)

CREATE TABLE B
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_file PRIMARY KEY (id ),
  CONSTRAINT fk_a_pk FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES A (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Please include the SQL DDL of your `A` and `B` tables. If possible, set the [`hibernate.show_sql` property](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-optional) in your `persistence.xml` and post the actual `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Please. In ADDITION section of my question.

Comment: A is an inverse side, and from the sql-queries I see that Hibernate attempt to **insert into B table before it make insert into A table**

Comment: How to set insert order? Why it insert in B firstly, if I use session.save(a)?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: `optional = false` on `A` tells Hibernate to insert into `B` first.

**Making the association unidirectional**

The JPA JavaDoc provides an example of a [one-to-one association that assumes both the source and target share the same primary key values](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html), but it uses an unidirectional association:

1. Remove the association from `A`:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class A {
       @Id
       @SequenceGenerator(...)
       @GeneratedValue(...)
       private long aId;
   }
   ```
2. If you are using an Hibernate version which supports JPA 2.0 (recent versions do), specify the `@MapsId` attribute on `B`, removing the foreign generator:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class B {
       @Id
       private long aId;

       @OneToOne
       @MapsId
       private A a;
   }
   ```

**Keeping the association bidirectional**

You cannot put `optional = false` on the `@OneToOne` annotation in `A`. Since the foreign key (`B.id`) referencing `A` is mandatory, you should insert into `A` first anyway:

```
INSERT INTO A (id) VALUES (1);
-- there isn't a corresponding record in B,
-- until we perform a second insert into B:
INSERT INTO B (id) VALUES (1);
```

Knowing this, let's make the association bidirectional again:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(...)
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private long aId;

    // should work without 'optional = false'
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a",  cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private B b;
}
```

See also [Primary Keys through OneToOne and ManyToOne Relationships](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Primary_Keys_through_OneToOne_and_ManyToOne_Relationships)

Comment: About 'should work without optional = false'  you are wrong. Yes, saving will work, BUT lazy loading - doesn't. Lazy loading for one-to-one assosiation should create a PROXY, but it can't if assossiation is optional.

Comment: But I want the assosiation be from A to B, and it be lazy. Does @MapsId support lazy loading and cascading?

Comment: I can't see why it shouldn't. Just try it out, and turn `hibernate.show_sql` on.